# quantmod::getSymbols() cannot retrieve data from Yahoo Finance

Tags: r, finance, quantmod, yahoo

**Update: April 29, 2022**

[As per this discussion in Github](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/358), Joshua Ulrich had uploaded a patch into Github which resolves the issue.

The issue was with Yahoo website having stopped to provide the crumb(s) that were expected by the `new.session()` but not essential for getting `getSymbols()` to work.

To install the patch, exit all R and RStudio sessions.  Start a new R or RStudio session.  Execute the commands

```
remotes::install_github("joshuaulrich/quantmod@358-getsymbols-new.session")
library("quantmod")
quantmod::getSymbols("TSLA")
```

**Original question**

Today (April 28, 2022) I got an unusual situation with `quantmod::getSymbols()`.

The following code works if executed in an RStudio session that was started yesterday (R version 4.2.0, Windows 10):

```
if (!require("quantmod")) install.packages("quantmod")
library("quantmod")
quantmod::getSymbols("TSLA")
```

However, the same code produces a timeout error in a new RStudio session on the same machine:

*Error in new.session() : Could not establish session after 5 attempts.*

What was tried:

1. Same code in [Jupyter notebook on a remote server](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/binder-examples/r/HEAD?filepath=index.ipynb) produces the same timeout.
2. Same code in a new RStudio (or R) session on a different Windows 10 computer produces the same timeout.
3. Same code in an RStudio (or R) session works if the session was started yesterday on either Windows 10 computer.
4. Same code on previous versions of R or RStudio works if the session was started yesterday on either Windows 10 computer.

Perhaps the `quantmod` package and `getSymbols()` have cached the SSL certificates?

Comment: I don't use `quantmod`, but can you confirm that the API it uses is in fact working today? Outages happen.

Comment: The API is working -- I am able to get the data for any stock symbol if I use the RStudio session that was started yesterday.  But, I cannot do that if I start a new session, locally or on a remote machine.

Comment: I had the same problem yesterday, but after a while it disappeared. Might just be worth the wait

Comment: I'm working on getting a fix to CRAN. You can use the development version in the meantime. Follow the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/358)

Comment: Thank you Joshua for fixing the problem!

Comment: Something very odd is happening with the new package.  I reinstalled quantmod and it appeared that it was working.  I was able to download price information at first.  But then in the middle of downloading price information for about 500 stocks, I started getting the "Error in Download" message.  It seems to start the error message after about 195 stocks.  That may be random, but I'm curious if there is a limit to how many stocks a person can download?   Then after I get the "Error in Download" message, I have to reinstall the package again, sometimes to no avail...  Any ideas?